# How to concatenate icons into a single image with ImageMagick?

Tags: graphics, bitmap, imagemagick, css-sprites

I want to use [CSS sprites](http://alistapart.com/articles/sprites) on a web site instead of separate image files, for a large collection of small icons that are all the same size. How can I concatenate (tile) them into one big image using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)?

Comment: Use the 'montage' tool: [here are some instructions](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php)

Comment: Not ImageMagick, but here are instructions on how to do this in Python using the Python Image Library:
http://29a.ch/2009/5/14/concatenating-images-using-python

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the page you linked, ['montage'](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) is the tool you want. It'll take a bunch of images and concatenate/tile them into a single output. Here's an example image I've made before using the tool:
[image]
<sub>(source: [davr.org](http://davr.org/ds2/demos2/index.png))</sub>

Answer (score 60):

[convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) works much better than montage. It arranges images vertically or horizontally and keeps png transparency.

```
convert *.png -append sprites.png (append vertically)
convert *.png +append sprites.png (append horizontally)
```

Comment: Well I didn't test, but it seems that -background None will allow transparent background (see http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#bg )

Comment: There is a problem that it seems to just append the pictures in random order despite I named them from 1.png to 15.png. Do you know how to make imagemagick append the pictures in a specified order?

Comment: @AnonJ, your shell might be expanding `*` to the list of filenames based on lexicographic ordering - that's what zsh is doing for me, at least.

Comment: @JonathanChan That's true. I forgot that numbers like 15 doesn't go well with such ordering. Anyways I ended up using some gem(compass-rails in this case) for sprite generation and didn't do it manually.

Comment: This is amazing. Is there a way to specify how many rows per columns? (or have columns, for that matter :P)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, montage uses the size of one frame to set all the frames inside in the resulting image. While 'convert append' appends one frame after the other making it as wide or tall as needed.

Answer (score 26):

You are looking for:

```
montage -background transparent -geometry +4+4 *.png sprite.gif
```

Answer (score 5):

I like this script for automatical sprite/css generation.
"[Building CSS sprites with Bash & Imagemagick](http://jaymz.eu/2010/05/building-css-sprites-with-bash-imagemagick/)"

- article copy in Waybackmashine https://web.archive.org/web/20150529041037/http://jaymz.eu/blog/2010/05/building-css-sprites-with-bash-imagemagick
- script copy http://blog.kupriyanov.com/2011/01/solvedbuilding-css-sprites-with-bash.html

Comment: @printminion That link is dead, too!